# optimizing rounded corners performance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following code in my UITableViewCell:

```
  [self.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [self.layer setShadowRadius:10.0];
    [self.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)];
    [self.layer setShadowPath:path.CGPath];
    [self.layer setShouldRasterize:YES];
    [self.layer setRasterizationScale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale];
```

when I run instrument and set color offscreen - rendered yellow, this causes the cell to be yellow. When I remove the shouldRasterize it doesn't shade the cells to yellow. What are ways to improve this? 
This is greatly hurting my scrolling performance. I am just trying to set rounded corners with some shadows in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing rounded corners like this:

```
    self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.05, 0.05);
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 10;
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 1.5;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    [self.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    [self.layer setBorderWidth: 5.0];
```

Comment: this didn't help. I tried, still gives me a yellow cell when I profile using color offscreen